# ERROR: gcloud crashed (TransferRetryError): Bad Request

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm running a daily dataproc job (pyspark), has been working fine for a year. Today, we're getting the following error:

```
ERROR: gcloud crashed (TransferRetryError): Bad Request
```

We got the error twice in a row, near the end of the job execution. It doesn't happen at a specific point in the job though.

I don't see much info about this error so I'd like to learn more about it and what could cause it.

Comment: Jobs seem to be working fine now.. My guess is that this has to do with the job logging but I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this may have been due to some sort of (transient?) (network?) error with gcloud rather than the job itself failing.

For future reference, if this happens in the middle of job execution, you can always rerun gcloud to poll for job completion. Doing so will print out all driver logs from the beginning and continue streaming as usual until completion:

```sh
gcloud dataproc jobs wait <job-id> [--region=<region>]
```

If you aren't sure of the corresponding job id, it should have been printed out at job submission time. You can also list the jobs for a given cluster:

```sh
gcloud dataproc jobs list --cluster=<cluster> [--region=<region>]
```

Comment: Yeah I was thinking that too, but this is not ideal since the job submit command fails and so I'd need to implement some kind of checking logic to double check that it really failed.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's a limitation of the current gcloud client implementation. If you're writing automation around Dataproc and you want to resubmit if the job _submission_ itself fails (rather than polling for the results), you should use one of the [Dataproc client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/api-libraries-overview). These client libraries are based on gRPC and make it easy to configure high-level retry logic.